# Characters get replaced when running script from batch

Tags: sql, regex, batch-file, db2

I had my fair share of questions and I got great answers from all of you.

I have a lot of queries running on a DB2 server and I decided to run them from a Batch file for ease of use. No problems here, except the fact that one of them consists of a multitude of 
replace statements where I change local chars to Latin chars.

```
(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('ä', 'AE'), 'Ä', 'AE'), 'ö', 'OE'), 'Ö', 'OE')
```

The problem is that by running this from a .bat file from the DB2CLP I get a "+" sign added right before some of the special characters so some get replaced, and others do not.

I have tried to replace them with the HEX code, but I still get some issues with HEX codes containing two sequential letters that give a parsing error.

Is there a better way to do this, maybe with a mapping table?

Thanks to advise,

Doru

Comment: `I get a "+" sign added right before some of the special characters so some get replaced, and others do not.` Can we see an example? Also, info about the version of DB2 might be needed. (Should we assume platform is Windows?)

Comment: Unix Server. HOW IT SHOULD BE:

a lot of (Replace(LOWER(NAME), '', X '0D'), '', X '0A')), ' ', '')), '_', ' ''.,-/()+~!<>@#$%^*?`"&', '_'), '_', ''), '', ''), 'ä', 'AE'), 'Ä', 'AE'), 'ö', 'OE'), 'Ö', 'OE'), 'ü', 'UE'), 'Ü', 'UE'), 'ß', 'SS')

HOW IT IS:

a lot of ( Replace (LOWER(NAME) '',  X'0D'),  '',  X'0A')),' ','') ) , '_' , ' ''.,-/()+~!<>@#$%^*?`"&' , '_' ) , '_' , '' ) , '┬æ' , '' ) , '├ñ' , 'AE' ) , '├ä' , 'AE' ) , '├╢' , 'OE' ) , '├û' , 'OE' ) , '├╝' , 'UE' ) , '├£' , 'UE' ) , '├ƒ' , 'SS' )

Comment: Please edit the question to add the examples and format them carefully. Having the examples written in a comment makes them difficult to read.